# How does the suppress with emitEarlywhenFull() for tumbling windows works?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I am using suppress on tumbling windows to get aggregated results. I am exploring both untilTimeLimit and untilWindowCloses for suppress. 
I dont want my streams to shutdown when buffer fulls. I have seen this feature  emitEarlyWhenFull() , but it cant be applicable on top of untilWindowCloses. 
Hence, i am picking untilTimeLImit with emitEarlyWhenFull() , please refer below code :

```
groupedStreams.windowedBy(TimeWindows.of(Duration.ofMinutes(5)))    
.aggregate(() -> initialBlob, blobAggregator,someserde)
.suppress(Suppressed.untilTimeLimit(Duration.ofMinutes(5), new StrictBufferConfigImpl().emitEarlyWhenFull()))
.toStream()
```

In my case, I am using tumbling windows for 5 mins. So, for every 5 mins, a window will be open for every record key. According to documentation, oldest records will be sent when the buffer gets filled. 
what happens to the new records with same key comes after old records sent down in the same tumbling window?

For Example : messages flow :
(A,1)
(A,2)
(A,3) -> agg result :  (A,6) . suppose here , the buffer is full, (A,6) will be sent downstream. Lets suppose (A,4) comes now in the same tumbling window, what will come next ? will it be : (A,10) or it will start fresh with (A,4) again?

Answer (score 0):

If `suppress()` emits, the state will be preserved. Thus, for your example, the aggregation will continue and eventually (A,10) will be emitted.